# I have a problem to connect to my amplify via amplify

Tags: angularjs, aws-amplify

I'm using AWS Amplify on my project, everything works fine locally, but when I ran git push to deploy some changes to GitHub and deploy my app to AWS Amplify, everything also works fine.

When my CI / CD process is complete, I cannot log into my app because I am having this problem:

AuthError -
Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly.
The configuration object is missing required auth properties.
This error is typically caused by one of the following scenarios:

```
        1. Did you run `amplify push` after adding auth via `amplify add auth`?
            See https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#amplify-project-setup for more information

        2. This could also be caused by multiple conflicting versions of amplify packages, see (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/troubleshooting/upgrading/q/platform/js) for help upgrading Amplify packages.
```

PS : I don't have this problem locally only on amplify.

does anyone have an idea please ?

Comment: PS : I don't have this problem locally only on the cloud *.

Answer (score 1):

Plese Check App.js and try to add following lines.

```
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
// >>New - Configuring Auth Module
Auth.configure(awsconfig);
```

Some Times this problem occurs under various Amplify module versions due to inconsistencies between installed Amplify modules. In my cases, reinstalling @aws-amplify/ui-components if you use it